# What is this style of text-as-image called?

Tags: typography, terminology

I'm seeing a trend (especially on pinterest) of these posters where the image and subject is the text. THe text itself isn't really that important either, it's mainly the typefaces used and composition.

Does this style have a name to it? Is it just called text-as-image?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd generally call this kind of graphics **typographic artwork** or, from the times when these advertising graphics and commercial signage were drawn by hand, **lettering artwork**. This is especially true for the second example (blue). The first one maybe not so much.

See also: letter art.

There is also a different genre of graphics called 'typographic art'.

Answer (score 3):

These aren't anything specific other than nostalgic/retro.

The first one is emulating newsprint using a course line screen. It appears to be using wood type-style typefaces as well (an odd mix of styles, actually).

The second one is just a classy type lock-up with lots of borders and embellishments.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those would be retro styles. The first one is also (and mostly) grunge

This is how I have tagged them and mostly how I have seem them tagged by others

Comment: It's interesting that people see this as "retro", particularly the bottom one.

Comment: is there any other ways to see them (now i am interested to know myself)? obviously besides typographic

Comment: Well retro usually refers to something that was trendy a number of decades earlier, whereas I don't think that second one in particular is referencing any particular earlier trend.  That sort of typographic play seems very trendy right now, actually, and if I had to pick which decade it came from, I'd say the current one.

Comment: here is a list of retro typography http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/26/retro-and-vintage-typography-showcase/ and the "live together forever" design seems the same as the second one. Also this old style designs are popular today, but I dont think that makes the style new. I dont know, just a thought.

Comment: I don't think that one is retro either (even though a lot of the other stuff in that article *is*).  But that's just me!  At no point did I say you were wrong - just that it's not the way I think of it.

Comment: cool. I'll keep my eye on this style from now on, as Im not sure either :)