# What is a text heavy design with multiple types of typography called?

Tags: typography, advertising

Can anyone tell me the name of the design style used for these types of designs? If there is a name for them, even. They're text heavy with different typography on just about every line and a sort of controlled chaos.  I'm trying to find a good set of examples online but it's not Googling well and this isn't my area of expertise.  Thanks in advance.

[image]

---

Actually, after reading [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15640/what-is-this-style-of-text-as-image-called?rq=1) and searching some more, I feel like it's a bad imitation of hand lettering  which will help to solve my problem. I may have phrased the question poorly due to my ignorance.  Thank you all for your help anyway.

Comment: "A text heavy ad with multiple types of typography" sounds good to me. I don't think there is an official name for it.

Comment: Looks like an [infographic](http://gog.is/images+infographic), though I'm not sure if they're for advertising.

Comment: @Dominic that was my first thought too...even though it's not an infographic it has some similarities in style. (If it means anything though, I don't think this is a good mix of typefaces.)

Comment: A text composition? I am not sure though :)

Comment: It's called.. design.... :)

Comment: Given that example, I'd use the term 'tacky' or maybe 'cluttered'

Comment: Well, I didn't preface "design" with an adjective. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I don't think there's one specific name for that. If you weren't feeling too charitable you could call it a pastiche... but more usefully that style of design pretty much arose out of mid to late 19th to early 20th century broadsheets.

Comment: I guess it is a pastiche in a way.  Considering it imitates the style of hand lettering to some degree. Not quite what I was looking for but thank you for the help none the less.

Answer (score -1):

You might find some similar stuff searching for **Infographics**.